# Should I use a Inline If statment or handle the test in a method

Tags: c#, if-statement, inline

I've the following class

```
public static class Translation
{
    public enum LanguageCultureName
    {
        enGB,
        zhCN
    };

   public static string Get(LanguageCultureName languageCultureName, string sValue)
   {
        if (languageCultureName == LanguageCultureName.enGB)
        {
            return sValue;
        }
        else
        {
            //get translated string
            return ....
        }
   }
}
```

Basically I'm looking to call the method like

Is it preferable to put an inline If statement around the method call like;

```
LanguageCultureName languageCultureName = LanguageCultureName.zhCN;
string sTranslation = languageCultureName == LanguageCultureName.enGB ? "My String to translate" : Translation.Get(languageCultureName, "My String to translate");
```

,or just call it, and if it is enGB return the passed string like

```
LanguageCultureName languageCultureName = LanguageCultureName.zhCN;
string sTranslation = Translation.Get(languageCultureName, "My String to translate");
```

Are there any performance reasons for this, or is it personal preference ?

Comment: Why would you do the first version? Isn't that just duplicating the logic?

Comment: Well, if I used the first version, I'd remove the test in the method if (languageCultureName == LanguageCultureName.enGB)

Comment: @Tommo1977, yes you would remove that "if" test and method call which by the way has no relevant performance costs. And by doing so, you just added another (inline) if... Doh!

Comment: If you are worried about optimization, consider that method calls do add extra complexity (if the compiler doesn't optimize it out).  However, there is no other real reason to choose one over the other except readability.

Comment: @NathanA, [Micro-Optimization Theater](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater/) is no real reason regarding translation of text resources... ;)

Comment: @elgonzo that really depends on the use. If it was a translation that is used for a load unit test, for example, it could be very relevant.  That's why I said, "**if** you are worried about optimization".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is abstraction that should happen inside the `Get` method, not inlined.

```
LanguageCultureName languageCultureName = LanguageCultureName.zhCN;
string sTranslation = Translation.Get(languageCultureName, "My String");
```

I should also note that having the enGB strings hardcoded is not a good practice. You should move *both* the enGB and zhCN strings to external resources files (e.g. .resx).

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the second one. There will be very little performance impact but it is more readable.

The way I understand your code is that you want check if the culture is already in English or not and return the standard string if it is instead of translating it. In order for this to make a performance impact you have to take a few aspects in account

- How often do you expect the culture to be in English?
- How intensive is the translating operation?
- Can you pass around a non-english string as input?

Each of these remarks will have influence over your eventual design. You seem to be entertaining the thought of removing the english `if` altogether and replace it with a ternary statement, aka: removing an `if` and adding an `if` in the wrong place.

And having considered all that: if your validation whether or not it's an english culture is the first statement inside your method, there will never be a notable difference between that and putting it outside in the ternary statement.

Let's not forget one of the ten comandments:

> We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil.